# Upgrading to Nodejs 8 and "error: failed to commit transaction"

Tags: node.js, linux, archlinux

I am trying to upgrade my nodejs 6 to 8 in my arch linux. So I did:

```
$ sudo pacman -S nodejs npm
```

Result:

```
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (3) openssl-1.0-1.0.2.l-1  nodejs-8.1.3-1  npm-4.6.1-1

Total Installed Size:  39.22 MiB
Net Upgrade Size:       6.79 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] y
(3/3) checking keys in keyring                                                                                    [####################################################################] 100%
(3/3) checking package integrity                                                                                  [####################################################################] 100%
(3/3) loading package files                                                                                       [####################################################################] 100%
(3/3) checking for file conflicts                                                                                 [####################################################################] 100%
error: failed to commit transaction (conflicting files)
openssl-1.0: /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 exists in filesystem
openssl-1.0: /usr/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0 exists in filesystem
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
```

And now my nodejs is broken I think!

```
$ node --version
node: error while loading shared libraries: libhttp_parser.so.2.7.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas what should I do now?

Comment: Does upgrading `openssl` first and then trying helps?

Comment: @dlmeetei how do I upgrade `openssl`?

Comment: @dlmeetei but first of all, is this correct command to upgrade nodejs `sudo pacman -S nodejs npm`? It looks like a command for installing but not upgrading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had same problem and this is how I solve it :

```
sudo pacman -S nodejs npm --force
```

Option --force will upgrade your package even if you get warning with existing files.

After this you need to install http-parser with pacman so :

```
sudo pacman -S http-parser --force
```

Finally, node -v will give you this error :

> error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.59: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

To fix it, install icu lib from pacman :

```
sudo pacman -S icu --force
```

Here we go, your node version is now v8.4.0.

**Edited 17/01:** --force was deprecated. Please use --overwrite

Comment: This broke my setup: pacman: error while loading shared libraries: libicuuc.so.59: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: `--force` is deprecated. Use `--overwrite` instead.